# Reducer not rendering items in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this reducer which shall return all comments on the page :

```
case actionTypes.GET_COMMENT:
        return {
            ...state,
            comments: action.comments
        }
    export const getComment = (comments : Object[]) => {
    return {
        type : actionTypes.GET_COMMENT,
        comments
    }
}
```

Here is how i call it in component

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getAllCommentsOnCurrentPostFromBE = (id: Number) => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/getComment/${id}`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log('--------res,get', res.data);
                dispatch(actions.getComment(res.data))
                console.log('--------posts', posts);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('--------err', err);
            })
    }
    getAllCommentsOnCurrentPostFromBE(grabIdFromLocation())
},[])
```

`res.data` is collection of key value pairs like this {"comment":"123"}
But it is not rendering anything,any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `dispatch()` function. Downloaded data do not pass to the reducer. You have to use `redux-thunk` to use async functions with redux.

I recommend using actions in separate files:

```
export const fetchDataFromDatabase = () => async (
  disapatch,
  getState,
) => {
  const response = await axios.get();
  disapatch({
    type: TYPE,
    data: response.data,
  });
};
```

Then export your component `export default connect(yourProps,{fetchDataFromDatabase})(YourComponent)`

In your component you can call `props.fetchDataFromDatabase()`